# Combining multi coloumn failover logic into a single property in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

i am working on a legacy enterprise database that uses multiple columns to retrieve a part number the sql we currently use checks for a part number and if the part number is null then checks for the child part number what would be the best way of combining this logic into a single ef model property (eg  Product.PartNumber )

I would like this to be invisible as possible  so that only PartNumber is visible externally to the data api

Comment: ps this is for reporting only so insert logic is not important to the business logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in theory couldnt you do something like this

```
public class Part
{ 
    public string PartNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.PartId ?? this.ChildPartId;
        }  
    }

    internal string PartId { get; set; }
    internal string ChildPartId { get; set; }
}



public class PartsContext : DbContext
{ 
    public DbSet<Part> Parts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Part>().Ignore(e => e.PartNumber);   
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

or is this still considered bad

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code-first approach the only way is to do a projection in custom linq-to-entities query:

```
var products = context.Products
                      .Select(p => new SomeNonMappedType
                           {
                               Id = p.Id,
                               // All other fields
                               PartNumber = p.PartNumber ?? p.Child.PartNumber // I hope this will work
                           });
```

If you are using EDMX you can use `DefiningQuery` or `QueryView` but whole your new entity will be readonly. More about those in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602016/is-orm-possible-with-entity-framework/6603492#6603492).

Comment: being readonly is not dealbreaker for the app im writing so that would be fine if define a property as say public string PartNumber {get{ //your select logic }} 

would that work out ok or would that poison the model

ps i am using codefirst

Comment: Adding reference to context in your entity will poison the model. If you want a property you need a special type and method on the context returning the result of the query I posted.